# Keras: CNN model is not learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I want to train a model to predict one's emotion from the physical signals. I have a physical signal and using it as input feature;

> ecg(Electrocardiography)

In my dataset, there are **312** total records belonging to the participants and there are **18000** rows of data in each record. So when I combine them into a single data frame, there are **5616000** rows in total.

Here is my `train_x` dataframe;

```
            ecg  
0        0.1912 
1        0.3597 
2        0.3597 
3        0.3597 
4        0.3597 
5        0.3597 
6        0.2739 
7        0.1641 
8        0.0776 
9        0.0005 
10      -0.0375 
11      -0.0676 
12      -0.1071 
13      -0.1197 
..      ....... 
..      ....... 
..      ....... 
5616000 0.0226
```

And I have 6 classes which are corresponding to emotions. I have encoded these labels with numbers;

> anger = 0, calmness = 1, disgust = 2, fear = 3, happiness = 4, sadness = 5

Here is my train_y;

```
         emotion
0              0
1              0
2              0
3              0
4              0
.              .
.              .
.              .
18001          1
18002          1
18003          1
.              .
.              .
.              .
360001         2
360002         2
360003         2
.              .
.              .
.              .
.              .
5616000        5
```

To feed my CNN, I am reshaping the train_x and one hot encoding the train_y data.

```
train_x = train_x.values.reshape(312,18000,1) 
train_y = train_y.values.reshape(312,18000)
train_y = train_y[:,:1]  # truncated train_y to have single corresponding value to a complete signal.
train_y = pd.DataFrame(train_y)
train_y = pd.get_dummies(train_y[0]) #one hot encoded labels
```

After these processes, here is how they look like;
**train_x after reshape;**

```
[[[0.60399908]
  [0.79763273]
  [0.79763273]
  ...
  [0.09779361]
  [0.09779361]
  [0.14732245]]

 [[0.70386905]
  [0.95101687]
  [0.95101687]
  ...
  [0.41530258]
  [0.41728671]
  [0.42261905]]

 [[0.75008021]
  [1.        ]
  [1.        ]
  ...
  [0.46412148]
  [0.46412148]
  [0.46412148]]

 ...

 [[0.60977509]
  [0.7756791 ]
  [0.7756791 ]
  ...
  [0.12725148]
  [0.02755331]
  [0.02755331]]

 [[0.59939494]
  [0.75514785]
  [0.75514785]
  ...
  [0.0391334 ]
  [0.0391334 ]
  [0.0578706 ]]

 [[0.5786066 ]
  [0.71539303]
  [0.71539303]
  ...
  [0.41355098]
  [0.41355098]
  [0.4112712 ]]]
```

**train_y after one hot encoding;**

```
    0  1  2  3  4  5
0    1  0  0  0  0  0
1    1  0  0  0  0  0
2    0  1  0  0  0  0
3    0  1  0  0  0  0
4    0  0  0  0  0  1
5    0  0  0  0  0  1
6    0  0  1  0  0  0
7    0  0  1  0  0  0
8    0  0  0  1  0  0
9    0  0  0  1  0  0
10   0  0  0  0  1  0
11   0  0  0  0  1  0
12   0  0  0  1  0  0
13   0  0  0  1  0  0
14   0  1  0  0  0  0
15   0  1  0  0  0  0
16   1  0  0  0  0  0
17   1  0  0  0  0  0
18   0  0  1  0  0  0
19   0  0  1  0  0  0
20   0  0  0  0  1  0
21   0  0  0  0  1  0
22   0  0  0  0  0  1
23   0  0  0  0  0  1
24   0  0  0  0  0  1
25   0  0  0  0  0  1
26   0  0  1  0  0  0
27   0  0  1  0  0  0
28   0  1  0  0  0  0
29   0  1  0  0  0  0
..  .. .. .. .. .. ..
282  0  0  0  1  0  0
283  0  0  0  1  0  0
284  1  0  0  0  0  0
285  1  0  0  0  0  0
286  0  0  0  0  1  0
287  0  0  0  0  1  0
288  1  0  0  0  0  0
289  1  0  0  0  0  0
290  0  1  0  0  0  0
291  0  1  0  0  0  0
292  0  0  0  1  0  0
293  0  0  0  1  0  0
294  0  0  1  0  0  0
295  0  0  1  0  0  0
296  0  0  0  0  0  1
297  0  0  0  0  0  1
298  0  0  0  0  1  0
299  0  0  0  0  1  0
300  0  0  0  1  0  0
301  0  0  0  1  0  0
302  0  0  1  0  0  0
303  0  0  1  0  0  0
304  0  0  0  0  0  1
305  0  0  0  0  0  1
306  0  1  0  0  0  0
307  0  1  0  0  0  0
308  0  0  0  0  1  0
309  0  0  0  0  1  0
310  1  0  0  0  0  0
311  1  0  0  0  0  0

[312 rows x 6 columns]
```

After reshaping, I have created my CNN model;

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(100,700,activation='relu',input_shape=(18000,1))) #kernel_size is 700 because 18000 rows = 60 seconds so 700 rows = ~2.33 seconds and there is two heart beat peak in every 2 second for ecg signal.
model.add(Conv1D(50,700))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(4))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(6,activation='softmax'))

adam = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0, amsgrad=False)

model.compile(optimizer = adam, loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['acc'])
model.fit(train_x,train_y,epochs = 50, batch_size = 32, validation_split=0.33, shuffle=False)
```

The problem is, accuracy is not going more than 0.2 and it is fluctuating up and down. Looks like the model does not learn anything. I have tried to **increase layers**, **play with the learning rate**, **changing the loss function**, **changing the optimizer**, **scaling the data**, **normalizing the data**, but nothing helped me to solve this problem. I also tried more simple Dense models or LSTM models but I can't find a way which works.

How Can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

**Addition:**

I wanted to add the training results after 50 epochs;

```
Epoch 1/80
249/249 [==============================] - 24s 96ms/step - loss: 2.3118 - acc: 0.1406 - val_loss: 1.7989 - val_acc: 0.1587
Epoch 2/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 76ms/step - loss: 2.0468 - acc: 0.1647 - val_loss: 1.8605 - val_acc: 0.2222
Epoch 3/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 76ms/step - loss: 1.9562 - acc: 0.1767 - val_loss: 1.8203 - val_acc: 0.2063
Epoch 4/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 75ms/step - loss: 1.9361 - acc: 0.2169 - val_loss: 1.8033 - val_acc: 0.1905
Epoch 5/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 74ms/step - loss: 1.8834 - acc: 0.1847 - val_loss: 1.8198 - val_acc: 0.2222
Epoch 6/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 75ms/step - loss: 1.8278 - acc: 0.2410 - val_loss: 1.7961 - val_acc: 0.1905
Epoch 7/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 75ms/step - loss: 1.8022 - acc: 0.2450 - val_loss: 1.8092 - val_acc: 0.2063
Epoch 8/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 75ms/step - loss: 1.7959 - acc: 0.2369 - val_loss: 1.8005 - val_acc: 0.2222
Epoch 9/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 75ms/step - loss: 1.7234 - acc: 0.2610 - val_loss: 1.7871 - val_acc: 0.2381
Epoch 10/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 75ms/step - loss: 1.6861 - acc: 0.2972 - val_loss: 1.8017 - val_acc: 0.1905
Epoch 11/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 75ms/step - loss: 1.6696 - acc: 0.3173 - val_loss: 1.7878 - val_acc: 0.1905
Epoch 12/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 75ms/step - loss: 1.5868 - acc: 0.3655 - val_loss: 1.7771 - val_acc: 0.1270
Epoch 13/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 75ms/step - loss: 1.5751 - acc: 0.3936 - val_loss: 1.7818 - val_acc: 0.1270
Epoch 14/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 75ms/step - loss: 1.5647 - acc: 0.3735 - val_loss: 1.7733 - val_acc: 0.1429
Epoch 15/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 75ms/step - loss: 1.4621 - acc: 0.4177 - val_loss: 1.7759 - val_acc: 0.1270
Epoch 16/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 75ms/step - loss: 1.4519 - acc: 0.4498 - val_loss: 1.8005 - val_acc: 0.1746
Epoch 17/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 75ms/step - loss: 1.4489 - acc: 0.4378 - val_loss: 1.8020 - val_acc: 0.1270
Epoch 18/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 75ms/step - loss: 1.4449 - acc: 0.4297 - val_loss: 1.7852 - val_acc: 0.1587
Epoch 19/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 75ms/step - loss: 1.3600 - acc: 0.5301 - val_loss: 1.7922 - val_acc: 0.1429
Epoch 20/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 75ms/step - loss: 1.3349 - acc: 0.5422 - val_loss: 1.8061 - val_acc: 0.2222
Epoch 21/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 75ms/step - loss: 1.2885 - acc: 0.5622 - val_loss: 1.8235 - val_acc: 0.1746
Epoch 22/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 75ms/step - loss: 1.2291 - acc: 0.5823 - val_loss: 1.8173 - val_acc: 0.1905
Epoch 23/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 75ms/step - loss: 1.1890 - acc: 0.6506 - val_loss: 1.8293 - val_acc: 0.1905
Epoch 24/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 75ms/step - loss: 1.1473 - acc: 0.6627 - val_loss: 1.8274 - val_acc: 0.1746
Epoch 25/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 75ms/step - loss: 1.1060 - acc: 0.6747 - val_loss: 1.8142 - val_acc: 0.1587
Epoch 26/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 75ms/step - loss: 1.0210 - acc: 0.7510 - val_loss: 1.8126 - val_acc: 0.1905
Epoch 27/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 75ms/step - loss: 0.9699 - acc: 0.7631 - val_loss: 1.8094 - val_acc: 0.1746
Epoch 28/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 75ms/step - loss: 0.9127 - acc: 0.8193 - val_loss: 1.8012 - val_acc: 0.1746
Epoch 29/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 75ms/step - loss: 0.9176 - acc: 0.7871 - val_loss: 1.8371 - val_acc: 0.1746
Epoch 30/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 75ms/step - loss: 0.8725 - acc: 0.8233 - val_loss: 1.8215 - val_acc: 0.1587
Epoch 31/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 75ms/step - loss: 0.8316 - acc: 0.8514 - val_loss: 1.8010 - val_acc: 0.1429
Epoch 32/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 75ms/step - loss: 0.7958 - acc: 0.8474 - val_loss: 1.8594 - val_acc: 0.1270
Epoch 33/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 75ms/step - loss: 0.7452 - acc: 0.8795 - val_loss: 1.8260 - val_acc: 0.1587
Epoch 34/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 75ms/step - loss: 0.7395 - acc: 0.8916 - val_loss: 1.8191 - val_acc: 0.1587
Epoch 35/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 75ms/step - loss: 0.6794 - acc: 0.9357 - val_loss: 1.8344 - val_acc: 0.1429
Epoch 36/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 75ms/step - loss: 0.6106 - acc: 0.9357 - val_loss: 1.7903 - val_acc: 0.1111
Epoch 37/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 75ms/step - loss: 0.5609 - acc: 0.9598 - val_loss: 1.7882 - val_acc: 0.1429
Epoch 38/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 75ms/step - loss: 0.5788 - acc: 0.9478 - val_loss: 1.8036 - val_acc: 0.1905
Epoch 39/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 75ms/step - loss: 0.5693 - acc: 0.9398 - val_loss: 1.7712 - val_acc: 0.1746
Epoch 40/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 75ms/step - loss: 0.4911 - acc: 0.9598 - val_loss: 1.8497 - val_acc: 0.1429
Epoch 41/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 75ms/step - loss: 0.4824 - acc: 0.9518 - val_loss: 1.8105 - val_acc: 0.1429
Epoch 42/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 75ms/step - loss: 0.4198 - acc: 0.9759 - val_loss: 1.8332 - val_acc: 0.1111
Epoch 43/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 75ms/step - loss: 0.3890 - acc: 0.9880 - val_loss: 1.9316 - val_acc: 0.1111
Epoch 44/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 75ms/step - loss: 0.3762 - acc: 0.9920 - val_loss: 1.8333 - val_acc: 0.1746
Epoch 45/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 75ms/step - loss: 0.3510 - acc: 0.9880 - val_loss: 1.8090 - val_acc: 0.1587
Epoch 46/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 75ms/step - loss: 0.3306 - acc: 0.9880 - val_loss: 1.8230 - val_acc: 0.1587
Epoch 47/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 75ms/step - loss: 0.2814 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 1.7843 - val_acc: 0.2222
Epoch 48/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 75ms/step - loss: 0.2794 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 1.8147 - val_acc: 0.2063
Epoch 49/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 75ms/step - loss: 0.2430 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 1.8488 - val_acc: 0.1587
Epoch 50/80
249/249 [==============================] - 19s 75ms/step - loss: 0.2216 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 1.8215 - val_acc: 0.1587
```

Comment: your validation loss doesn't change but loss decreases during training. at this point your model has probably overfitted, and you can reduce your epochs, and additionally consider simplifying the network and seeing if that helps. (disclaimer, didn't look into model code itself)

Comment: @ParitoshSingh, yes it is obviously overfitting but until it overfits, there is no satisfying result. The accuracy fluctuates all the way down. I have tried simpler models, nothing changed.

Comment: Frustrating one, for sure. Since `validation_split` just pulls from the end of each batch, could there be a per-batch pattern resulting in validation data being substantially different from training? Perhaps you've already tried `shuffle = True`?

Comment: @TheLoneDeranger, yes I have tried `shuffle = True`, it didn't change anything.

Comment: you could try regulation https://keras.io/regularizers/ to avoid overfitting

Comment: maybe as a start: if subject i‘s emotion in time t is contingent on i‘s emotion in t-1, your model will be unable to capture this dynamic reaction. A easy way to check if this could be the problem is to run an OLS model and add lagged emotions. This is in R, but it is a good intro to time series in Keras https://blogs.rstudio.com/tensorflow/posts/2017-12-20-time-series-forecasting-with-recurrent-neural-networks/

Comment: @Peter, actually to make a Time series classification, I have tried a LSTM model but the accuracy was too low as well.

Comment: Maybe the problem is with the data itself? Since you tried regularization techniques and LSTMs, perhaps there is something wrong with your data.

Comment: Looks like a time series problem to me. Reccurent neural networks is probably what you need.
Could you share a sample of your dataset to play with?

Comment: Is dataset publicly available or it is created by you?. And if it's publicly available, where can I find that?

Comment: @kruxx, here is the raw, not preprocessed dataset. Note that it is very noisy data and should be preprocessed. https://github.com/ozanyurtsever/emotion_recognition/tree/master/splitted_datasets

Comment: @OzanYurtsever, **In addition** to setting `shuffle = True`, try to shuffle your training data before fitting them into your model.

Comment: Your training set is too small for the amount of parameters you are using, unless you give the system a reasonable prior it will probably take forever to converge on something and when it does it wont generalize well. I would suggest if you insist on only using this small set you look into incorporating uncertainty (Bayesian Networks) into your model. Look for some work by Yarin Gal and related authors and mainly variational inference.

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend taking several steps back and consider a much simpler approach.  
Based on the following...

> I have tried to increase layers, play with the learning rate, changing the loss function, changing the optimizer, scaling the data, normalizing the data, but nothing helped me to solve this problem. I also tried more simple Dense models or LSTM models but I can't find a way which works.

It doesn't sound like you have as strong of an understanding of your data and your tooling... which is fine cause it's an opportunity to learn.

A few questions

1. Do you have a base line model?  Have you tried just running a multinomial logistic regression?  If not I would strongly suggest starting there.  Going through the feature engineering needed to make such a model will be invaluable as you increase the complexity of your model.
2. Did you check for class imbalances?
3. Why are you using a CNN?  What do you want to accomplish with the convolutional layers?  For me when I'm constructing a vision model for let say classifying the shoes in my closet I use several convolutional layers to extract spatial features such as edges and curves.
4. Related to the third question... Where did you get this architecture from?  Is it from a publication?  Is this the current state of the art model for ECG traces? Or is this the most accessible model?  Sometimes the two are not the same.  I would dig into the literature and search the web a bit more to find some more information about neural networks and analyzing ECG traces.

I think if you can answer these questions you will be able to solve your problem yourself.

Comment: Actually with the most of researches have been made on this area, CNN structure is used. I decided use it after reading several papers on this topic.

Comment: @OzanYurtsever Ok cool! In those papers do they have a baseline model you can implement?  Is the model you used in your question base on the baseline model in the paper?  Have you tried reproducing the author's results using their methods and data?

Answer (score 2):

Current problem in your implementation is, as you have used data with shape of  `(312,18000,1)` for your model, you only have 312 samples and you have used 0.33 validation split so, you are using only 209 samples for training purpose.

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d_1 (Conv1D)            (None, 17301, 100)        70100     
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_2 (Conv1D)            (None, 16602, 50)         3500050   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 16602, 50)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 16602, 50)         200       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 16602, 50)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_1 (MaxPooling1 (None, 4150, 50)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 207500)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 6)                 1245006   
=================================================================
Total params: 4,815,356
Trainable params: 4,815,256
Non-trainable params: 100
_________________________________________________________________
```

As I seen `model.summary()`, your model has 4,815,256 total trainable parameters.  So, your model is easily overfitting the training data. Issue is, you have so many parameters to learn without enough samples. You can try to reduce your model size as shown below:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(100,2,activation='relu',input_shape=(18000,1))) 
model.add(Conv1D(10,2))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(4))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(6,activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
```

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d_1 (Conv1D)            (None, 17999, 100)        300       
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_2 (Conv1D)            (None, 17998, 10)         2010      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 17998, 10)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 17998, 10)         40        
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 17998, 10)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_1 (MaxPooling1 (None, 4499, 10)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 44990)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 6)                 269946    
=================================================================
Total params: 272,296
Trainable params: 272,276
Non-trainable params: 20
_________________________________________________________________
```

As I know you have 3 types of data ecg, gsr, temp. So, you can use `train_x` as (312,18000,3). and your `train_y` will be `(312,6)`.

If above solution is not working than,

1. Plot the class distribution from your dataset and check if there is any
   class imbalance in data.
2. As your model is overfitting the data, try to create more data (If this dataset is created by you) or find some data augmentation technique for this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your code is correct, but as the commenter said, you are likely overfitting your data.

You might want to plot validation accuracy and training accuracy over the epochs to visualize this.

You should first consider seeing if your overfitting issue improves with a simpler model. Note that this will not likely improve your over all performance, but your validation accuracy will more closely match whatever your training accuracy becomes. Another option would be to add a pooling layer immediately after your convolution layers.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to add regularizer(s) (L1 or L2), check `kernel_initializer` and/or adjust the learning rate during training via callbacks. The example below is from a regression model.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, input_dim=dims, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='normal', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1(x)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal'))

model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.adam(lr=l), loss='mean_squared_error')

reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', factor=0.5, patience=3, min_lr=0.000001, verbose=1, cooldown=0)

history = model.fit(xtrain, ytrain, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, validation_split=0.3, callbacks=[reduce_lr])
```

Comment: I have tried all of the methods which you mentioned but unfortunately, none of them was helpful to my problem.

Comment: Mmmm... okay. Did you try other methods, such as RF boosting, a la lightGBM or catboost? Or is there a time dimension? In this case Keras LSTM could work...

Comment: nope I didn't try any of these methods. Maybe I should search about them and try to implement into my code.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that the way train_y was preprocessed, it could not properly sync with your train_x. My question would be, did you compress your y_train following some frequency based technique ? 

I think if you have compressed your labels (for each row) by some frequency based technique, you have already introduced high bias on your data. Do let me know how the compression was done ! Thanks

Comment: There were no spesific preprocessing method applied to train_y except the one hot encoding method.

Comment: Ok I understand. So that means each sample has one dimensional physical 18000 signals and 18000 corresponding labels. Don't you think this distribution structure is not healthy for training? Correct me if I have interpreted the structure wrongly.

Comment: actually with the line of code `train_y = train_y[:,:1] ` I am converting y_train to shape of (312,1).  With that, there is only one corresponding label value for every 18000 signal.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

1. I see that number of data points is less. More the complexity of the problem, more data points is required for a deep learning model to learn. 
   Look for a similar dataset with large amount of data. Train your network on that dataset and transfer it to your problem.
2. Is there a way to augment data?? I see your signal length as 18000. You can down sample the data by half using different techniques and augment the dataset. You will be working with signal of length 9000.
3. Try reducing convolution kernel length to 3 or 5 and increase model depth by adding another conv layer.
4. I would strongly suggest to try random forest an gradient boosted trees and see how they perform.

Comment: The convolutional kernel lenght is 700 because in the dataset, 700 rows ~= 2 second and in every 2 seconds, there is 2 heart beat peaks(R peaks). I wanted CNN recognizies this patters and extract features.

Answer (score 0):

I have face ECG problem when I did my final assignment in college a year ago, but with different approach and data (MIT-BIH).

It seems you use single lead, isn't it? Have you try to prepare the data before like clean it up (mind the heartbeat noise)?  My suggestion is, try to not combine all data into one single list for training, that can occur over fit due the nature of human heartbeat, try to make training based from gender or age. In some literature, it pretty helps.

Model are not working properly, not because a wrong implementation, but sometimes how we prepare the data well.

Answer (score 0):

Your model is clearly overfitting the dataset. One suggestion that nobody has taken into account among the commenters is to increase the stride. Here you have `kernel size = 700`, no padding and `stride = 1`. So you will obtain an output with shape `(None, 17301, 100)` from the first Conv layer.

I would try to either increase the stride to a number in the order of 50 to 100 (shifting your kernel of a fraction of `2.33/(700/stride)` seconds) or insert a Pooling layer after each of the Conv layers.